# QGIS processing algorithm, nested algorithm run returns string

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I am building a custom processing script using the `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` class.

In the early part of my algorithm, I am processing an input feature using the native 'centroids' algorithm. I want to access this output and continue with my algorithm, however the `'OUTPUT'` key from the `processing.run` call only returns a string.

I initialize the input feature as:

```
   def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        """Defines input and output."""

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.REFERENCE,
                "Choose input grid",
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
                )
            )
```

and inside the processAlgorithm() method I use:

```
        # get centroids
        parameters_centroids = {
            "INPUT": parameters[self.REFERENCE],
            "ALL_PARTS": False,
            "OUTPUT": "memory":
        }
        centroids = processing.run("native:centroids", 
            parameters_centroids, is_child_algorithm=True,
            context=context, feedback=feedback)["OUTPUT"]
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}
        
        feedback.pushInfo(f"{type(centroids)}")
```

The actual process runs without errors and gives feedback `'Results: {'OUTPUT': 'output_22428702_fd31_459d_9454_fce67f3e9f14'}'` (or some other memory pointer).

The `feedback.pushInfo()` call gives `<class 'str'>` and prevents me from further processing the output from the centroids algorithm. I would expect the type to be a `QgsVectorLayer`.

Is this because of saving the output to `'memory:'`?

This is an intermediate step in the algorithm I would happily avoid saving the centroids output. I believed loading layers only had to be done when processing from the console.

Comment: The string is likely a reference to the layer's in-memory ID. Try `centroids = QgsVectorLayer(centroids, 'centroids')` and continuing with your processing as intended.

Comment: I tried this but it returns a QgsVectorLayer with a 'featureCount()' of -2 ? Also, I tried my first attempt while looking at for example [this tutorial script](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_python_scripts.html) where they get the layer directly from the 'OUTPUT' key.

Comment: An update: If I return the intermediate layer as an OUTPUT, I can see that the process has been running as expected and the output is indeed a point vector layer. However I still want to access it as a vector layer within my script (access methods like 'featureCount()'). Matt's comment leaves me with a vector layer that is not behaving as the output from the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution looking at [a related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361353/store-result-of-a-processing-algorithm-as-a-layer-in-qgis-python-script).

The solution lies in retrieving the output layer into the processing script's context using the 'QgsProcessingContext' and its 'takeResultLayer' which can take a context and a memory id (string) as arguments. For me, it was used as follows

```
# get centroids
parameters_centroids = {
    "INPUT": parameters["REFERENCE"],
    "ALL_PARTS": False,
    "OUTPUT": "memory:"
}
centroids = processing.run("native:centroids", 
    parameters_centroids, is_child_algorithm=True,
    context=context, feedback=feedback)["OUTPUT"]
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {} 
centroids_layer = QgsProcessingContext.takeResultLayer(context, centroids) # type QgsVectorLayer

# centroids_layer can now be processed further.. like:
number_of_features = centroids_layer.featureCount()
```

note that `context` is an attribute of the processAlgorithm class using the current QGIS framework for processing scripts.